# How to Requery a subform inside a form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having a problem in which I can't requery a subform inside of a form in Access.

The form's name is frmSearch
The subform's name is SearchResults

I've tried

```
Private Sub Command38_Click()

Me!SearchResults.Form.Requery (or)
Me.SearchResults.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

My form & subform look like this:

[image]

To be clear, I'm using the "Search" button to create a string which contains the textbox and combobox values. This string creates a SQL query called qryTrialQuery. Then my subform makes a query of the qryTrialQuery and produces the results in the table bellow.

I would like to be able to press the search button and then the results appear below it immediately after. The problem is, is that the results don't appear unless I close and reopen the form.

Thanks for all your help in advance.

---

**Update**

The following is the code I used to create a query from the textbox and combobox values.

```
LineOne = "SELECT tblPoolPersonnel.LName, tblPoolPersonnel.FName, tblPoolPersonnel.[Tel Natel], tblPoolPersonnel.[Tel Home], tblPoolPersonnel.Email" & vbCrLf
LineTwo = "FROM (tblPoolPersonnel INNER JOIN tblDayAvailable ON tblPoolPersonnel.Code_Personal = tblDayAvailable.Code_Personal) INNER JOIN tblServiceYES ON tblPoolPersonnel.Code_Personal = tblServiceYES.Code_Personal" & vbCrLf
LineThree = "WHERE (((tblServiceYES.Service)=" & comboService & ") AND ((tblDayAvailable.Availability)=True) AND ((tblDayAvailable.Date)=" & txtDate & ") AND ((tblDayAvailable.CodeHoraire1)=" & comboCodeHoraire & "));"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myQuery")
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
strSQL = LineOne & LineTwo & LineThree
qdf.SQL = strSQL
qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Comment: Where is the code where you do something with the search form and qryTrialQuery? Are you sure that the subform **control** is called SearchResults? A subform consists of a control and the form contained. You must use the name of the control when referring from a form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are reconstructing the SQL of your query based on the criteria the user selected, you should just be able to do something like this:

```
Private Sub Command38_Click()
    Dim qryTrialQuery as String
    ...
    ' code to construct the SQL SELECT statement for the query, '
    ' based on the criteria the user entered                    '
    ...
    SubForm.Form.RecordSource = qryTrialQuery
End Sub
```

Setting the Subform's `RecordSource` will refresh the data.

Comment: Great Solution. Not only are my search results updated immediately after pressing the search button, but it eliminates the need to create a separate Query file. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Dim frm as Form
Set frm = frmSearch
frmSearch!SearchResults.Form.Requery
```