# Subquery / Subform doesn't refresh

Tags: ms-access

I have an SQL table with hundreds of thousands of entries that I want to give users the option to filter based on certain criteria. I tried to get the job done in Excel, but since users need to see several layers of subtotals both a table with subtotals and a pivot table just don't cut it.

I've connected the SQL table to Access and can get the refresh working there just fine. I've then created a report to display the result set in an appropriate manner for the end user. What I now need is a form that allows the user to set the range of entries they want to see - for that I've created 2 dropdown combo boxes acting as the range delimiters. The top and bottom delimiter of those boxes then feed into a query that only returns the entries between those 2 values.

Choosing / changing values in the combo box form causes the query to requery properly. When I'm trying to just display the results of the query line for line in a subform, I simply can't get the subform / subquery to refresh.

I've tried all kinds of Me.Form.Refresh / Requery's, even some weird and obscure methods where you had to set, clear and then reset the cache before requerying, but I just couldn't get it to work. Found a lot of mentions of having to set child/parent relations in the subform's properties, but those apparently don't exist anymore in Access 2007-2016.

Pretty much out of ideas at this point. Anyone any ideas on what I could be missing?

Comment: Without code to work against we are guessing.  Perhaps you are using the subform that access creates by default.  The default subform does not work in all respects.  Create a copy of your whole form (safety first).  then delete the copy's subform  and replace it with a duplicate subform (it can be as simple as drag and drop so look it up)  You will now be able to edit the subform on the duplicate to your hearts content including the master-child.  Also the master-child relationship is on the subform control that wraps the actual subform.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To requery the subform from your parent form, you should use the following syntax, where you replace *MySubForm* with the name of your subform:

```vb
Me!MySubForm.Form.Requery
```

Or if you must do it from another form, then you can do this:

```vb
Forms![MyMainForm]![MySubForm].Form.Requery
```

If that does not work then check out these questions [How to Requery a subform inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427201/how-to-requery-a-subform-inside-a-form) or [Access subform not refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810625/access-subform-not-refreshing-displayed-records) or [Cannot refresh subform from other subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764184/cannot-refresh-subform-from-other-subform)

Comment: Putting both of these into the after_update event still doesn't update the embedded subform.  

`Private Sub combobox1_bis_AfterUpdate()

Me!frmSub.Form.Requery
Forms![frmMain]![frmSub].Form.Requery

End Sub`

The subform on its own is properly refreshing, but the subform embedded in the mainform simply won't update.

Comment: Have you read the other questions? And if those do not help, then maybe update your question and explain in more detail, maybe include some more source code and source data.

Answer (score 0):

We should to understand the issue technically. when we do changes in the main form, it remains as draft till the record complete or save. So we are require to save the record on combo updates.  we just need a line code on combo afterupdate

Me.Form.Requery